# How can I write this algorithm that returns the count between x and y in a list?

Tags: list, algorithm, dictionary, pseudocode

I am given this algorithmic problem, and need to find a way to return the count in a list S  and another list L that is between some variable x and some variable y, inclusive, that runs in O(1) time:

> I've issued a challenge against Jack. He will submit a list of his favorite years (from 0 to 2020). If Jack really likes a year,
> he may list it multiple times. Since Jack comes up with this list on the fly, it is in no
> particular order. Specifically, the list is not sorted, nor do years that appear in the list
> multiple times appear next to each other in the list.

> I will also submit such a list of years.

> I then will ask Jack to pick a random year between 0 and 2020. Suppose Jack picks the year x.

> At the same time, I will also then pick a random year between 0 and 2020. Suppose I
> pick the year y. Without loss of generality, suppose that x ≤ y.

> Once x and y are picked, Jack and I get a very short amount of time (perhaps 5
> seconds) to decide if we want to re-do the process of selecting x and y.

> If no one asks for a re-do, then we count the number of entries in Jack's list that are
> between x and y inclusively and the number of entries in my list that are between x and
> y inclusively.

More technically, here is the situation. You are given lists S and L of m and n integers,
respectively, in the range [0, k], representing the collections of years selected by Jack and
I. You may *preprocess* S and L in O(m+n+k) time. You must then give an algorithm
that runs in O(1) time – so that I can decide if I need to ask for a re-do – that solves the
following problem:

**Input:** Two integers, x as a member of [0,k] and y as a member of [0,k]

**Output:** the number of entries in S in the range [x, y], and the number of entries in L in [x, y].

For example, suppose S = {3, 1, 9, 2, 2, 3, 4}. Given x = 2 and y = 3, the returned count
would be 4.

I would prefer pseudocode; it helps me understand the problem a bit easier.

Comment: Make a histogram, and then compute the accumulated sum for each entry in the histogram. Suppose `S={3,1,9,2,2,3,4}` and `k` is 9. The histogram is `H={0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,1}`. After accumulating, `H={0,1,3,5,6,6,6,6,6,7}`. Given x=2 and y=3, the count is `H[y] - H[x-1] = H[3] - H[1] = 5 - 1 = 4`. Of course, x=0 is a corner case that has to be handled.

Comment: @user3386109 if you didn't know k ahead of pre-processing, how would the algorithm change?

Comment: If you aren't given `k`, you can perform an O(m+n) scan of the two input arrays, find the maximum value, and call that `k`. The `k` you find may be less than the actual `k`, but that's not a problem. The algorithm needs `k` to size of the histogram correctly. Of course, if `x` or `y` or both are larger than the computed `k`, then that's another corner case for you to handle.

Comment: @user3386109 So, what would a proof that shows that this algorithm wont just output a number that is not the actual entries kinda look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing the approach of **user3386109** taking care of edge case of x = 0.

**user3386109** : Make a histogram, and then compute the accumulated sum for each entry in the histogram. Suppose S={3,1,9,2,2,3,4} and k is 9. The histogram is H={0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,1}. After accumulating, H={0,1,3,5,6,6,6,6,6,7}. Given x=2 and y=3, the count is H[y] - H[x-1] = H[3] - H[1] = 5 - 1 = 4. Of course, x=0 is a corner case that has to be handled.

```
# INPUT

S = [3, 1, 9, 2, 2, 3, 4]
L = [2, 9, 4, 6, 8, 5, 3]
k = 9

x = 2
y = 3

# Histogram for S
S_hist = [0]*(k+1)

for element in S:
    S_hist[element] = S_hist[element] + 1

# Storing prefix sum in S_hist 
sum = S_hist[0]
for index in range(1,k+1):
    sum = sum + S_hist[index]
    S_hist[index] = sum


# Similar approach for L

# Histogram for L
L_hist = [0] * (k+1)

for element in L:
    L_hist[element] = L_hist[element] + 1
    
# Stroing prefix sum in L_hist
sum = L_hist[0]
for index in range(1,k+1):
    sum = sum + L_hist[index]
    L_hist[index] = sum
    
# Finding number of elements between x and y (inclusive) in S
print("number of elements between x and y (inclusive) in S:")
if(x == 0):
    print(S_hist[y])
else:
    print(S_hist[y] - S_hist[x-1])
    
# Finding number of elements between x and y (inclusive) in S
print("number of elements between x and y (inclusive) in L:")
if(x == 0):
    print(L_hist[y])
else:
    print(L_hist[y] - L_hist[x-1])
```

Comment: I think `S_hist[element] = S_hist[element] + 1` will print this: `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2...]`

Comment: @JohnAdams No, it is an array indexing method(Hashing) of elements from 0 to k with index(key) as an element with value as how many times that element occurred.

Comment: Right, but the line `S_hist = [0]*(k+1)` seems to be making the condition of the for loop `S_hist[element] = S_hist[element] + 1` affect every element in the list, instead of it what it is intended to do, which is affect only index `element`.

Comment: ope, never mind, you are right. I was working with `S_hist = [[0,0]]*(k+1)` to see if I can combine S and L into one histogram, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @JohnAdams Instead of using this command: S_hist = [[0,0]]*(k+1)    Use a loop to add [0,0] -> k+1 times.

Comment: @JohnAdams If my answer solves your issue, Could you accept it, please?

Comment: Sure, so what would a proof that shows that this algorithm wont just output a number that is not the actual entries kinda look like/

Comment: @JohnAdams We are doing hashing of elements and then doing prefix sums. As we are subtracting prefix sums out of a range from a given range, then there will be no element outside a given range(x and y).